# Create file on GAE/J and upload to Google docs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-docs-api

Is it possible to create any kind of file on GAE/J and upload to google docs? I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996495/uploading-a-pdf-file-to-google-docs-generated-by-pdfjet-on-gae-j) before about creating and uploading PDF.

Thanks.

Update

According to Google Docs API "To upload a document to the server, you can attach the file to the new DocumentListEntry using the setFile() method.". And setFile method needs java.io.File which is not accepted by GAE/J setFile(java.io.File file, java.lang.String mimeType). Is there a solution I can upload without storing data. I need java.io.File type as an argument for the setFile() method  to work. I've tried using gaevfs(http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/)+appengine-java-io(http://code.google.com/p/appengine-java-io/) but the type File within appengine-java-io does not match the type File used in setFile() method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading a PDF file to Google Docs generated by pdfjet on GAE/J](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996495/uploading-a-pdf-file-to-google-docs-generated-by-pdfjet-on-gae-j)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions - update your existing question if you have more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Nick Johnson I found the way to upload PDF on GAE/J. I was not aware of the method setMediaSource() for PdfEntry. At least the examples nor any of the codes I've found. I've tried almost every example, solution but at last I found another code while looking for something else. In case someone else who needs it the answer is below. Most of the code is PDF generation which is taken from the samples of pdfjet [webpage](http://pdfjet.com/java/examples/example-10.html) Thanks everyone for help.

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDF pdf = new PDF(os);
        Font f1 = new Font(pdf, "Helvetica");
        Font f2 = new Font(pdf, "Helvetica-Bold");
        Font f3 = new Font(pdf, "Helvetica-Bold");
        pdf.setTitle("Using TextColumn and Paragraph classes");
        pdf.setSubject("Examples");
        pdf.setAuthor("Innovatics Inc.");
        Page page = new Page(pdf, Letter.PORTRAIT);
        f1.setSize(12);
        f2.setSize(16);
        f3.setSize(14);
        TextColumn column = new TextColumn(f1);
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.setAlignment(Align.CENTER);
        p1.add(new TextLine(f2, "Switzerland"));
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.add(new TextLine(f2, "Introduction"));
        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
        p3.setAlignment(Align.JUSTIFY);
        TextLine text = new TextLine(f2);
        text.setText("The Swiss Confederation was founded in 1291 as a defensive alliance among three cantons. In succeeding years, other localities joined the original three. The Swiss Confederation secured its independence from the Holy Roman Empire in 1499. Switzerland's sovereignty and neutrality have long been honored by the major European powers, and the country was not involved in either of the two World Wars. The political and economic integration of Europe over the past half century, as well as Switzerland's role in many UN and international organizations, has strengthened Switzerland's ties with its neighbors. However, the country did not officially become a UN member until 2002. Switzerland remains active in many UN and international organizations but retains a strong commitment to neutrality.");
        text.setFont(f1);
        p3.add(text);
        Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph();
        p4.add(new TextLine(f3, "Economy"));
        Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph();
        p5.setAlignment(Align.JUSTIFY);
        text = new TextLine(f1);
        text.setText("Switzerland is a peaceful, prosperous, and stable modern market economy with low unemployment, a highly skilled labor force, and a per capita GDP larger than that of the big Western European economies. The Swiss in recent years have brought their economic practices largely into conformity with the EU's to enhance their international competitiveness. Switzerland remains a safehaven for investors, because it has maintained a degree of bank secrecy and has kept up the franc's long-term external value. Reflecting the anemic economic conditions of Europe, GDP growth stagnated during the 2001-03 period, improved during 2004-05 to 1.8% annually and to 2.9% in 2006. Even so, unemployment has remained at less than half the EU average.");
        p5.add(text);
        Paragraph p6 = new Paragraph();
        p6.setAlignment(Align.RIGHT);
        text = new TextLine(f1);
        text.setColor(RGB.BLUE);
        text.setText("Source: The world fact book.");
        text.setURIAction("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/sz.html");
        p6.add(text);
        column.addParagraph(p1);
        column.addParagraph(p2);
        column.addParagraph(p3);
        column.addParagraph(p4);
        column.addParagraph(p5);
        column.addParagraph(p6);
        column.setPosition(90, 300);
        column.setSize(470, 100);
        column.drawOn(page);
        pdf.flush();
        docsService.setOAuthCredentials(getOAuthParams(), new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
        URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"+folderID+"/contents?xoauth_requestor_id="+user.getEmail());
        PdfEntry newDocument = new PdfEntry();
        newDocument.setCanEdit(true); 
        newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Sample Report"));
        newDocument.setMediaSource(new MediaByteArraySource(os.toByteArray(), "application/pdf"));
        docsService.insert(feedUrl, newDocument);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the GData APIs for Documents. You can find information about the API itself [here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) (specifically the part about [Uploading Documents](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs)), and [this link](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#googledata) will be helpful in setting it up to work in Google App Engine.

Comment: There is not a problem in uploading, the problem is creating a file in GAE/J. GAE does not allow to create file so I can set the file argument in Google Docs API.

Comment: Files are just blobs of data stored in a filesystem. There's no need to store your data in a filesystem - just create it in your App Engine app and upload it directly.