# GAE/J: Writing PDF data to a Google Doc

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In GAE/J, I need to generate a PDF and somehow place it into a ResumableGDataFileUploader to be uploaded to Google Docs. I can't dump the data into a File because GAE/J doesn't support any classes that can read or write to a file.

Does anyone know of a good way to fill in the rest of this code?

```
DocsService docsService = ...
Asset asset = new Asset("text/html", getHTML().getBytes(), "");
Document document = new Document(asset);
Conversion conversion = new Conversion(document, "application/pdf");
ConversionService service = ConversionServiceFactory.getConversionService();
ConversionResult result = service.convert(conversion);
for (Asset assetIter : result.getOutputDoc().getAssets()) {
    byte[] data = assetIter.getData();
    //How do I get the generated PDF into the ResumableGDataFileUploader?
    ...
    ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder builder = new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read, write and create files using the files API in the blobstore.

Comment: I tried placing the PDF into the Blobstore, but I am stuck on trying to create a MediaFileSource (a required parameter for ResumableGDataFileUploader).  It requires a java.io.File type, and I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: have you seen this q&a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013723/create-file-on-gae-j-and-upload-to-google-docs

Comment: Yes, but I need to use ResumableGDataFileUploader.  I can't use DocsService.insert.  (Or did I miss something in that Q&A?)

Comment: When you use the blobstore, you do not need gdata. See : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview You need gdata  when you upload a document not with the blobstore, but with google drive and you want to access the content of a document.